# react-dom-router Link component doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app with two pages--- the home and trip page. The trip page is rendered with the tripID passed in through the url. My app.js looks like :

```
function App() {
  return (<>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/trip/:tripId' element={<TripComponent />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </>
  );
}
```

I have a global navbar with a menu of different `tripIds` as many `Link` to navigate to the TripComponent. When i am at the `"/"` path, and I navigate to `"/trip/tripA"`, i have no problems. But when i am at `"/trip/tripA"` , and i want to navigate to `"/trip/tripB"`, it doesnt work. I can see the url changing accordingly, but my `TripComponent` doesnt rerender with tripB's data. the code for my menu in my navbar looks like:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(<>
    <CustomModal setOpen={setShowTripList} title={"Saved Trips"}>
            <List>
                {trips && trips.length > 0 &&
                    trips.map((trip, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Link to={`/trip/${trip._id}`} >
                                <ListItemButton>
                                    <ListItemText id={trip._id} primary={trip.title} />
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </Link>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </List>
    </CustomModal>
</>
    , document.getElementById("portal"))
```

I am confused as to why this is happening. When i press the `Link` to navigate to another URL, shouldn't it unmount and remount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `tripId` route path parameter updates the routed element `TripComponent` isn't remounted, it is only rerendered. If there is some logic that depends on the `tripId` path parameter then `TripComponent` needs to "listen" for changes to that value. This is the same thing that would need to happen if a prop value changed.

Use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `tripId` path parameter to issue side-effects based on the current value.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const TripComponent = () => {
  const { tripId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // initial render or tripId updated
    // do something with current tripId value
  }, [tripId]);

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the @Drew's answer is perfect.
But I'd like to put something additionally.

I suggest you to use useMemo hook.

```
...
const trip = useMemo(() => {
    // something you want
}, [tripId])
...
```

Comment: appreciate the answer! but for my use case of async operations, i dont find useMemo to be of benefit.